# How to check if particular view is animating?

Tags: android, animation, android-recyclerview

I am animating view rows while adding it in infinite recyclerview. When I scroll very fast some view rows sticks on the screen. How to check if particular view is animating? So that I will not add any item to recyclerview if any view is animating

Comment: This sounds like you are doing something very wrong. What you are talking about shouldn't be possible unless you do something terrible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is reproducible when I scroll very fast.
I resolved this issue by clearing animation in onViewDetachedFromWindow of recyclerview's adapter

```
 public void onViewDetachedFromWindow(UserCardHolder userCardHolder) {
    super.onViewDetachedFromWindow(userCardHolder);
    userCardHolder.getView().clearAnimation();
}
```